# jQuery datatable doesn't get responsive in a row that is placed inside another div

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, datatables

I have a jQuery Bootstrap DataTable that doesn't get responsive when the row is placed inside another div. When I  have this row outside that div, everything is as expected. What should I fix in order to have responsiveness?

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="tables" role="tabpanel">
                           <div class="row">
                               <div class="col">
                                    <table class="table table-spacing table-borderless responsive nowrap" data-table="true" data-page-length="5">
                                        <thead class="thead-light">
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>1</th>
                                                <th>2</th>
                                                <th>3</th>
                                                <th>4</th>
                                                <th>5</th>
                                                <th>6</th>
                                                <th>7</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Type 1</td>
                                                <td>John Doe</td>
                                                <td>2483</td>
                                                <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</td>
                                                <td>20/07/2020</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <span>31/07/2020</span>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                            
                            <div class="box">
                                <h4>Datable with borders and no space between rows</h4>
                                <table class="table table-bordered responsive nowrap" data-table="true" data-page-length="5">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Name</th>
                                        <th>Surname</th>
                                        <th>Age</th>
                                        <th>Address</th>
                                        <th>Town</th>
                                        <th>State</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>John Doe</td>
                                        <td>System Architect</td>
                                        <td>B1</td>
                                        <td>43</td>
                                        <td>123, OneStreetTwo /td>
                                        <td>MI</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                                </table>
                        </div>
```

The jQuery code is:

```
$(document).on("datatable", function (e, param) {
    var table = $('[data-table="true"]').DataTable({
        dom: '<"row table-header-toolbar"<"col-sm-auto table-toolbar-left"l><"col table-toolbar-right"fB>>rt<"row table-footer-toolbar"<"col-sm-auto table-toolbar-left"i><"col table-toolbar-right"p>>',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'copy',
                text: '<i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-test1"></i>'
            },
            {
                extend: 'collection',
                text: '<i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-test2"></i>',
                buttons: [
                    'excel',
                    'csv',
                    'pdf',
                ],
                fade: true
            },
            {
                extend: 'colvis',
                text: '<i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-test3"></i>'
            },
            //'colvis',
            {
                extend: 'print',
                text: '<i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-test4"></i>'
            },
        ],
        lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
        rowReorder: false,
        paging: true,
        ordering: true,
        info: true,
        select: {
            style: 'multi',
            items: 'row',
            blurable: true
        }
    });
});
```

What do I need to modify in jQuery and/or in Bootstrap in order to have the table responsive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to recalculate column widths of all visible tables once a tab becomes active by using a combination of columns.adjust() and responsive.recalc() API methods.

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e){
   $($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable()
      .columns.adjust();
      .responsive.recalc();
});
```

More about this here: [Fixing DataTables issue in Bootstrap 4 tab](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-column-width-issues-with-bootstrap-tabs/)